# WP - Marketplace misssing required metadata

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, marketplace, windows-store

I tried to publish my windows phone app on marketplace but I have this error and I cant figure out how can I repair it:

```
Submission errors
    MyAppWinPhone.xap 

        Czech 
            Missing required metadata: Tile icon 
            Missing required metadata: Screenshot WVGA 

        English (International) 
            Missing required metadata: Tile icon 
            Missing required metadata: Screenshot WVGA
```

App is based on SDK 7.1

How can I repear this validation erorrs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App store need Tile icon and at least one screen shoot of application  at the time of submit, without this it will not submit completely and may show error.
Explore option and check your error,
There will be an option like **Show my Errors**. sheck this out.